# django celery chord task error

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

I have error when i am trying to use chord to send a task after all the tasks have been sent.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/wenzhixue/projects/workspace/fallfor_core/twitter/tasks.py", line 13, in bulk_change_bio
    chord([change_bio_task.delay(account,'http://fallfor.com') for account in account_list ])(shutdown.s(c))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/celery/canvas.py", line 470, in __call__
    _chord = self.type
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/celery/canvas.py", line 467, in type
    return self._type or self.tasks[0].type.app.tasks['celery.chord']
AttributeError: 'AsyncResult' object has no attribute 'type'
```

-

```
@task()
def shutdown(ec2):
    print "shutting down!!!!"
    time.sleep(300)
    return True

c = Ec2()
account_list = Account.objects.all()
chord([change_bio_task.delay() for account in account_list ])(shutdown.s(c))
```

Answer (score 4):

[Chord](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/celery.html#celery.chord) accepts two parameters: first one list of subtasks which is called as a group and second optional is subtask used as a callback after whole tasks from list are finished.

[Example from API referance](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/celery.html#celery.chord):

```
res = chord([add.s(2, 2), add.s(4, 4)])(sum_task.s())
```

In your code you are passing as a first parameter list of AsyncResults not subtasks.
This should be correct:

```
chord([change_bio_task.s() for account in account_list ])(shutdown.si(c))
```

Take a look that I changed `shutdown.s(c)` to `shutdown.si(c)` which is immutable and ignores results returned finished `change_bio_task`.